# Input custom US telephone mask omitted while backspacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a custom US telephone mask on input using jQuery like -

```
(___) ___-____
```

It's working fine on keydown event.

```js
var telMask = "(___) ___-____";
var phoneNumberBuffer = "";

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".telephone").focus(function () { handleFocus(this); });
  $(".telephone").blur(function () { handleBlur(this); });
  $(".telephone").keydown(function (event) { formatPhoneNumber(this, event); });
});

function mergePhoneMask() {
  var tempMask = telMask;
  var tempPos;
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumberBuffer.length; i++) {
    tempPos = tempMask.indexOf("_");
    tempMask = tempMask.substr(0, tempPos) + phoneNumberBuffer.charAt(i) + tempMask.substr(tempPos + 1);
  }
  return tempMask;
}

function setPhoneNumCursor(elem) {
  var position = $(elem).val().indexOf("_");
  if (position < 0) { position = $(elem).val().length; }
  if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
    elem.focus();
    elem.setSelectionRange(position, position);
  }
  else if (elem.createTextRange) {
    var range = elem.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', position);
    range.moveStart('character', position);
    range.select();
  }
}

function formatPhoneNumber(elem, e) {
  var tempMask = telMask;
  var tempPos;
  if (e.which == 8) {
    phoneNumberBuffer = phoneNumberBuffer.substr(0, phoneNumberBuffer.length - 1);
    elem.value = mergePhoneMask();
  }
  if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 95 && e.which < 106)) {
    if (phoneNumberBuffer.length < 10) {
      // numpad keys don't match to charcode
      if (e.which > 95 && e.which < 106) {
        phoneNumberBuffer += (e.which - 96).toString();
      } else {
        phoneNumberBuffer += String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      }
      elem.value = mergePhoneMask();
    }
  }
  //e.preventDefault();
  if (phoneNumberBuffer.length == 10 || e.which == 9) {
    //$(elem).parent().next().next().find("input").focus();
  } else {
    setPhoneNumCursor(elem);
  }
}

function handleFocus(elem) {
  if (elem.value == "") {
    elem.value = telMask;
  }
  setPhoneNumCursor(elem);
}
function handleBlur(elem) {
  if (elem.value == telMask) {
    elem.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-input">
  <input name="telephone" maxlength="14" class="telephone" type="tel" size="14" autocomplete="tel">
</div>
```

Problem is, while continuing to press the backspace/delete, it removes the "(" at the beginning. I'm not sure if I missed anything here! I've some limitations to use other plugins. Thanks!

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oju78xch/3/) here!

Comment: Please include all code necessary here on Stack Overflow, not just on jsFiddle (i.e., include the `handleFocus`, `handleBlur`, and `formatPhoneNumber` functions in the snippet).

Comment: I suggest you use a prewritten input masking widget rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Snippet Updated!

Comment: @Bamar, I've some limitations to use some plugins.